# TestNG-Selenium - Unable to convert string value to Integer read from a Excel file

Tags: selenium, apache-poi

I am trying to read data from an excel file using POI framework in TestNG, Selenium. I am able to read String data from the cells. When there in Integer data in the cell, it throws an error saying it can't convert String data into Integer.

I tried getStringCellValue, getRawvalue methods but it doesnt work.

Last line of the code is where I have issue. There should be a way to read integer data from the excel cells. Not just text/string only.

Any suggestions please

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;

import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;

import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;


import java.io.FileInputStream;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import org.testng.Assert;

import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;

import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;

import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;

import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;

import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;

import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

@Test
public void test(

   FileInputStream aTestDataExcelFile = new FileInputStream(TestDataFile);
   XSSFWorkbook aExcelWBook = new XSSFWorkbook(aTestDataExcelFile);
   XSSFSheet aXSSFSheet = aExcelWBook.getSheet(SheetName);
   XSSFCell aCell = aXSSFSheet.getRow(i).getCell(0);

   int aReasoncode= aCell.getStringCellValue();
}
```

Comment: [Getting the cell contents](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellContents)

Comment: Thank You so much Axel Richter

Comment: Brian, I will be careful next time in formatting the code before posting.

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast it into integer like this

```
int aReasoncode = Integer.parseInt(aCell.getStringCellValue());
```

Comment: I did that change to the code. I am getting the following error now. Java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a STRING value from NUMERIC cell

Comment: If you don't have space in the cell, you can use getNumericCellValue() method.